# BST Implementation in Python and methods

Tags: python, oop, binary-search-tree

I just started coding in Python and while going through the implementation of BST in python around the internet, I realized 2 method with the same name were being used say for some operations like insert, find. Can anyone explain why we are doing this ? Is this some sort of convention ?

Here is the code

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.right = None
        self.left = None

    def insert(self, data):
        if self.data == data:
            return False
        else:
            if self.data < data:
                if self.right:
                    return self.right.insert(data)
                else:
                    self.right = Node(data)
            else:
                if self.left:
                    return  self.left.insert(data)
                else:
                    self.left = Node(data)


class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self,data):
        if self.root:
            return self.root.insert(data)
        else:
            self.root = Node(data)
```

Comment: You can name the methods whatever you want , but convention is to be descriptive and succinct. Are you really asking why two different classes have similar method names ?

Comment: What I'm asking is why implement the same method in Node and Tree class as well ? Cant we just specify one method ?

Comment: They're not the same method. They just have the same name, and they're related.

Comment: @user2357112. Word. Not to mention that most, but not all, of what the root does is delegate to a node.